# Как узнать есть ли в разъеме HDMI поддержка CEC?

Tags: linux, hdmi

На стороне телевизора можно найти в меню. А вот как узнать поддерживает ли видеокарта этот протокол перед тем как перекомпилировать линукс?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Краткий ответ: поддержки HDMI CEC в вашей видеокарте нет.

Конечно, если это не Raspberry Pi, но тогда и [пересобирать ядро не нужно](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberrypi-hdmi-cec/).

Я просмотрел несколько форумов и несколько спецификаций видеокарт в надежде найти хотя бы "support CEC: no" - нет даже упоминания этой технологии. Также я посмотрел доступные фильтры подбора видеокарт - такого фильтра тоже нет.

> I managed to confirm that CEC is still not supported on desktop GPU boards.

[Nvidia, 2015](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/hdmi-cec-support/31445/14)

Почему же нет поддержки?

- каких-то технологических ограничений нет
- технология рассчитана на бытовую технику, а не PC (само название говорит об этом: Consumer Electronics Control), то есть это нишевый сегмент
- для PC это не бесплатно, есть [патент](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20080172504?oq=20080172504) - по сообщению с этого [форума](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/hdmi-cec-support/31445/49)

Люди везде возмужены, озадачены,  но рабочее решение одно - переходник usb + hdmi.

### Список поддерживаемого PC железа

Вот из [этого документа](https://hverkuil.home.xs4all.nl/cec-status.txt) к проекту Linux TV я получил список поддерживаемых микросхем/процессоров.

HDMI Transmitters:

- Exynos4
- Exynos5
- STIH4xx HDMI CEC
- V4L2 adv7511 (same HW, but a different driver from the drm adv7511)
- stm32
- Allwinner A10 (sun4i)
- Raspberry Pi (RPi 4 is supported in 5.12)
- dw-hdmi (Synopsis IP)
- amlogic (meson ao-cec and ao-cec-g12a)
- drm adv7511/adv7533
- omap4
- tegra
- rk3288, rk3399
- tda998x
- DisplayPort CEC-Tunneling-over-AUX on i915, nouveau and amdgpu
- ChromeOS EC CEC
- CEC for SECO boards (UDOO x86).
- Chrontel CH7322

HDMI Receivers:

- adv7604/11/12
- adv7842
- tc358743

### Утилиты

Есть несколько утилит из пакета v4l-utils (дебиан): cec-ctl, cec-follower, cec-compliance. Даже не знаю, заработают они без пересборки ядра или нет.